# Translate my SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to convert my SQL code into c# code linq code. This is just a snip of my code as the actual code is too long.

```
My SQL 
    Declare @ReportDate DateTime = NULL
    SELECT DISTINCT LotId, PenId, SUM(Head) AS TotalHead
            INTO #LotPenAlloctionListTempTable
                FROM (
                        SELECT  lp.LotId, lp.PenId, lp.HeadCountInPen  AS Head
                            FROM scoFeedlot.LotPen AS lp    

                        UNION
                        SELECT LotHistory.LotId, LotHistory.PenId, IIF(LotHistory.Direction = 1, LotHistory.Head * -1, LotHistory.Head) AS Head
                            FROM scoFeedlot.LotHistory                      
                            WHERE CAST(LotHistory.MovementDate AS DATE) > '2017-7-27' AND LotHistory.IsPending = 0 AND LotHistory.IsCancelled = 0
                    ) A GROUP BY Lotid, PenId

    Select Distinct [scoFeedlot].[Pen].PenName,[scoFeedlot].LotMaster.Lotnumber,[scoFeedlot].LotPen.HeadCountInPen
    from 
    #LotPenAlloctionListTempTable
```

My C# code

```
public async Task<int> GetHeadCountInPenLotPens(DateTimeOffset date)
{
    var lotPens = await _context.LotPens.ToListAsync();
    var lotHistory = await _context.LotHistories.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: I dont think you can apply temp table or that IIF part in the linq

Comment: @SKLTFZ not as such but you can execute the same conceptual logic even more elegantly in LINQ and without leaving a database artifact like a batch scoped temp table.

Comment: rectification: you can do the IIF part (tested and kinda easy to do), but i really dont think it is possible for applying temp table.

Comment: What benefit will it have to do that? Performance? Better readability of code?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without your tables, but this should work:

```
var a = (_context.LotPen.Select(lp=> new LotPenHead 
                    { 
                       LotId= lp.LotId, 
                       PenId = lp.PenId, 
                       Head = lp.HeadCountInPen
                    })
          .Concat(_context.LotHistory
                       .Where(lh=>lh.MovementDate > new DateTime(2017,7,27) 
                               && !lh.IsPending && !lh.IsCancelled)
                       .Select(lh=>new LotPenHead 
                          { 
                               LotId= lh.LotId, 
                               PenId = lh.PenId, 
                               Head = lh.Direction == 1 ? -lh.Head : lh.Head
                          }));

var results = a.GroupBy(aa=>new {aa.LotId, aa.PenId}, aa=>aa.Head)
               .Select(aa=>new LotPenHead
                           {
                              LotId = aa.Key.LotId, 
                              PenId = aa.Key.PenId, 
                              Head=aa.Sum()
                           }).ToList();
```